# Rails - both model are has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Sorry, I am not very advanced in mapping out databases

I have a model similar to this: A teacher can have many students, and a student can have many teachers. So How would I make this? If a student could have only one teacher I know I would set an attribute like: teacher_id: integer, then when I want to create a student it would be similar to this

```
Student.create(:teacher_id => id)
```

or query similar to this:

```
Student.where(teacher_id: id)
Teacher.find(student.teacher_id)
```

But I am unsure of how to accomplish this if both are has_many relationships

Answer (score 1):

You can use rails `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship for your requirement. check this link for reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference

you need to use this relationship like this:

**teacher.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :students
```

**student.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers
```

then you need to add a migration to create a join table containing teacher_id and student_id

you should create name of your migration in alphabetical order like this:

```
rails g migration create_join_table_for_students_teachers student_id:integer teacher_id:integer
```

and then `rake db:migrate`

then you can access students of a single teacher like `teacher.students` etc.,

Hope this might help you in some way please go through the reference link once

Answer (score 0):

You're describing a has-and-belongs-to-many (HABTM) relation, which Rails supports in two ways: `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many :through`. You can read about them in the [Active Record Associations Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many), which also gives you tips and how to choose which one is appropriate for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Better use *has_many:through* relation.